# Vue 3 Better performance of lot of DOM elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a big fat sort of table with lots of elements that make it really buggy.

For context 1 row per user, each user has X projects and each project has 3 month of day display  [(sort of gantt)](https://binaries.templates.cdn.office.net/support/templates/fr-fr/lt16400962_quantized.png)

So I built something cool it's working great, but if I scale to more users it begin to be real buggy.
I'm implementing filter to display less users but at some point it need to handle the limit that I have now without being buggy.

What I found is when I'm updating a day it re-render the whole Gantt which is really stupid.

here is a minimal reproduction link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-g6azah?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev

As you can see when I'm updating an input with the v-model:

```
value.value
```

I have the attribute with the function

```
:test="testRerender()"
```

That trigger for the whole Gantt and I believe it is the issue here.

I saw [v-memo](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo) that look like what I need but I can't figure out with the doc how can I use it to match my needs (and there is almost no good article on it)

Thanks for your help you would save my life!

I tried to filled proper :key attribute, code optimization, v-memo etc...

Comment: Use computed properties and avoid calling functions from the template, because it's inefficient, the function will be called everytime, while the computed properties will only be recomputed if data/props changes

Comment: thanks for your answer @Lk77 yea i belive computed would work to display data but this isn't working for this use case cause here we have a two-way binding in our input so they will always re-render.

Comment: Take a look at [virtual scroll](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller). If you don't know how to use v-memo please specify what is your problem with it. The stackblitz link is not enough